# How to create Slack Slash Command automatically when user install Slack App in his team?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am developing Slack bot, and I want to provide users with ability to use slash commands eg /command1.

User deploys my Slack Bot via Slack Button. What options do I have to make this possible?

I attach screenshot of different other bots slash commands which I installed in my Slack command and did no any additional tweaking. How to do same?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused as to where you got stuck... the documentation for the Slack Button is here: https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button. It specifically calls out the ability to add slash commands. If you've run into specific trouble, please describe the issue and share code as applicable.

Comment: Oh! I should have read the documentation more closely! Now I see that is  simple and clear way to do it :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button
See: Attach a slash command to your app (optional)

Comment: This answers your question, but is not necessarily an answer to the question in the title. This answer explains how to create a slash command with the typical way. **Not Programmtically**. The correct answer at the time of writing (April 2016) is that it is not possible to programmatically create a new slash command :) So, maybe edit the title?

Comment: Yes, really. I think that the question "How to create Slack Slash Command programmatically?" is not accurate enough. I will fix the title to "How to create Slack Slash Command automatically when user install Slack App in his team? Will be this wording more correct in your opinion?

Comment: Yup, although really this is the way that it works for all OAuth integrations.